# What's the difference between Knockout.js and Rx.js?

Tags: knockout.js, reactive-programming, rxjs

Does anyone know the differences between [RxJs](http://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/Charles/Introducing-RxJS-Reactive-Extensions-for-JavaScript) and [Knockout](http://knockoutjs.com/)?  To me on the surface they seem to be trying to solve the same problem, to build an event driven UI.  But someone who has had experience with both, how do they differ/ how are they similar?  Can you describe something about them to help me choose?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Steve (the creator of Knockout) [explained the difference](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/07/05/introducing-knockout-a-ui-library-for-javascript/#comment-10656) on his blog:

> I’m very familiar with Rx for JavaScript, having recently used it
> heavily on a big project, and in fact aspects of the design of
> Knockout are made with my Rx experiences in mind.
>
> The key difference
> between Knockout’s implementation of the observer pattern and Rx’s is
> that Knockout automatically infers the associations and dependencies
> between observables from regular procedural code without you having to
> specify them up front though a special functional API. I wanted
> Knockout to use regular procedural/imperative-style code as it’s more
> familiar and approachable for most developers.
>
> Another difference is
> that Rx is optimised for composing streams of events without state. At
> first I was enthusiastic about this and its functional purity, but
> after some time it felt increasingly like I was jumping through
> awkward hoops and had to invent extra ways to simulate state to manage
> UI commands efficiently. That’s why, in Knockout, all observables can
> be treated as stateful - for example you can always read their latest
> value (which is cached, by the way - it doesn’t recompute until the
> underlying data changes).
>
> Rx goes further than Knockout into advanced
> ways of composing event streams, whereas Knockout goes further than Rx
> into UI development, letting you bind its observables to HTML DOM
> elements and templates and manipulate them any way you want. Rx is
> great at what it does but turned out not be be exactly how I wanted to
> build rich UIs - hence the design of Knockout.

Answer (score 23):

They're actually quite different frameworks, though I can see why you'd see crossover:

**RxJs** provides a means of composing operations against asynchronous streams, like events and web requests, and includes advanced scenarios like combining streams (when both A and B occur, start this, but cancel it if A or B occur again)

**Knockout** is an MVVM framework that allows you to manage the state of your user interface via a model that maps it's functionality. This allows your view's logic to be separated from your view.

Comment: I just wanted to note that you can now bridge between Rx- and Ko-Observables. See here:
https://github.com/cburgdorf/Knockout-Rx/blob/master/app/App.ViewModels.SearchViewModel.js

Comment: yeah.... knockout  observables are not reactive . Rxjs are